# How is Predef in Scala inherited?

Tags: scala

Comment in the source for the Predef states:

> The `Predef` object provides definitions that are accessible in all
>   Scala compilation units without explicit qualification.

How is Predefs inherited in Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler implicitly adds `import _root_.scala.Predef._` to every source file.

Comment: And there are options to turn it off, `-Yno-predef -Yno-imports` and a WIP to let you set what is imported (possibly `-Ypredef`).